# Rather weird integral

Tags: calculus, integration

I've reached a pretty weird integral
$$\int_0^{5} \frac{\ln(y)}{(y+3)\sqrt{y}} dy,$$
And I'm having some difficulties starting from the
$u$-substitution method. I had the intuition that
I may take $\sqrt{y} = u$ and thus $\frac{1}{2\sqrt{y}}dy = du.$
However, this method seems to get tangled with the issues related
to the natural log in the numerator. I felt that I could start on
integration by parts, but then I thought that there may be a cleaner
method with partial fractions. Could someone give me some suggestions
on either method in this problem?

Comment: There isn't any clean solution. This cannot be expressed in terms of elementary functions. As far as the definite integral goes, the function is not symmetrical about its limits or any such thing, so I guess evaluating it using numerical methods is the only way to solve it.

Comment: wolfram alpha can't find any closed form for this integral, so I suspect this to be pretty hard(if possible...)

Comment: Apparently you can express the result using polylogarithms: [wolframalpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+ln%28y%29%2F%28%28y%2B3%29\sqrt%28y%29%29).

Comment: You say you've "reached" a pretty weird integral - does that mean that your attempted solution of a problem led (after some steps) to this integral? In which case, please post the original problem, because there could have been a mistake in your working that led to this difficult integral.

Comment: Substitution and parts reduces to $\int\frac{\arctan x}{x}dx$ I think this is a well known non integrable in elementary functions.

Comment: @Shailesh... In fact "this" is a real number, so of course it is expressed in terms of elementary functions.  All constant functions are elementary.  We can say (as noted in the answer) the antiderivative involved is not elementary.

Comment: @GEdgar  Of course that is what I meant.  Hence my comment says...'As far as the definite...

Comment: After a couple of substitutions I found it unavoidable   that I needed $\int (x/\sin x)dx$.

Comment: @ReneSchipperus - It's Catalan's Constant - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan%27s_constant

Answer (score 13, accepted):

$$\int \frac{\log(y)}{(y+3)\sqrt{y}} dy$$
$t=\sqrt{y},\;\; y=t^2,\;\;dy=2t\,dt$
$$=4\int \frac{\log(t)}{t^2+3} dt$$
$u=\log(t),\;\;du=\frac 1t,\;\; v=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\arctan\left(\frac{t}{\sqrt{3}}\right),\;\; dv = \frac{1}{t^2+3}$
$$=4\left(\frac{\log(t)}{\sqrt{3}}\arctan\left(\frac{t}{\sqrt{3}}\right)-\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\int\frac{\arctan\left(\frac{t}{\sqrt{3}}\right)}{t}dt\right)$$
Looking at the final integral, we get that
$$\int\frac{\arctan\left(\frac{t}{\sqrt{3}}\right)}{t}dt$$
$$=\frac{i}{2}\left(\int\frac{\log\left(1-\frac{t}{\sqrt{3}}\right)}{t}dt-\int\frac{\log\left(1+\frac{t}{\sqrt{3}}\right)}{t}dt\right)$$
$$=\frac{i}{2}\left(I_1 - I_2\right)$$
$u=\frac{t}{\sqrt{3}},\;\; t=u\sqrt{3},\;\; dt=du\sqrt{3}$
$$I_1 = -\int\frac{-\log(1-u)}{u}du = -\operatorname{Li_2}(u) = -\operatorname{Li_2}\left(\frac{t}{\sqrt{3}}\right)$$
$u=\frac{-t}{\sqrt{3}},\;\; t=-u\sqrt{3},\;\; dt=-du\sqrt{3}$
$$I_2 = -\int\frac{-\log(1-u)}{u}du = -\operatorname{Li_2}(u) = -\operatorname{Li_2}\left(\frac{-t}{\sqrt{3}}\right)$$
Putting this all together, we get
$$\frac{4\log(t)}{\sqrt{3}}\arctan\left(\frac{t}{\sqrt{3}}\right)+\frac{i}{2\sqrt{3}}\left[\operatorname{Li_2}\left(\frac{t}{\sqrt{3}}\right)+\operatorname{Li_2}\left(\frac{-t}{\sqrt{3}}\right)\right]$$
$$=\color{red}{\frac{4\log(t)}{\sqrt{3}}\arctan\left(\frac{t}{\sqrt{3}}\right)+\frac{i}{4\sqrt{3}}\operatorname{Li_2}\left(\frac{t^2}{3}\right)}$$
This uses the Polylogarithm. Here is a [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm) to the Wikipedia page on the topic.

Comment: Use $\text{Li}_2(a)+\text{Li}_2(-a)=\dfrac{\text{Li}_2\big(a^2\big)}2$ to simplify the final result.

Comment: @Lucian Good catch! Completely missed that!

Comment: Classy stuff @BrevanEllefsen

Comment: I'm sorry if I'm missing something obvious but I don't quite understand how you got from the arctan integral to the log integrals :-) could you clarify?

Comment: @Ant He's using the complex logarithmic forms of the $\arctan$ function. See [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions#Logarithmic_forms)

Comment: @GregRos Oh I see.. perfect, thank you ;-)

Comment: @Ant converting to exponential form is a very common trick to evaluating trig functions in calculus for differentiation and integration. It isn't always the fastest method, but it is almost always easier to use (as the derivatives and antiderivatives of exponential and logarithmic forms are so simple). Another example of this could be proving the derivative of $sin(x)$. This is commonly done using two limits which must first be shown, especially $sin(x)/x$ as $x$ goes to $0$. With exponential forms none of this is needed... The answer comes only knowing that $D e^{ix} = ie^{is}$, easily proved

Comment: There is a small typo: it should be $du=\frac{dt}t$, not $du=\frac 1t$, and $dv = \frac{dt}{t^2+3}$, not $dv = \frac{1}{t^2+3}$ -- but I can't edit your post.

Comment: @Sasha good point!  While I agree,  editing the post would somewhat be spam for such a small change.  I would say it's probably more appropriate to just leave this as a comment :)

Answer (score 6):

This is more of a comment since I'm not sure this is what you're looking for but if you use $t=\sqrt y$ then $dy=2t\ dt$. The integrand becomes

$$2t \frac{\ln t^2}{(t^3+3t)}=4\frac{\ln t}{t^2+3}$$

Then by parts, $u=4\ln t$ and $dv=\frac{1}{t^2+3}$. This gives $du=\frac{4}{t}$ and $dv$ is a function of arctan.

This leave you with a new integrand which looks like $\frac{\arctan t}{t}$ which is POSSIBLE with polylogarithmic functions but not with elementary functions.